# Correct coordinates for matrix transformed Imageview

Tags: android, image, matrix, touch, image-rotation

I'm trying to implement a camera preview where user can insert images and drag/scale/rotate them as overlays. I'd also need to support zoom in/out on the camera preview which is in the background. User would be able to pinch to zoom the camera when pressing outside of the image.

The images which the user can add are ImageViews that have *match_parent* width and height and scale type matrix. I need to allow the touch events to pass thru to the background camera view if they're not directly touching the current image.

I found some code that allows me to perform the various image manipulations:

```
// ImageView drag, zoom, rotate related variable
// These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
Matrix mSavedMatrix = new Matrix();

// We can be in one of these 3 states
public enum ImageTouchMode {
    NONE,
    DRAG,
    ZOOM
}

ImageTouchMode mMode = ImageTouchMode.NONE;
// Remember some things for zooming
PointF mStartPoint = new PointF();
PointF mMidPoint = new PointF();
float mOldDist = 1f;
float[] mLastTouchEvent = null;
float mRotationDegrees = 0f;
float mBrightness = 0f;

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (!hitTestInImageMatrix(event)) {
        // only handle touch events inside the transformed image matrix, not the whole image view
        return false;
    }

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //first finger down only
            mSavedMatrix.set(mMatrix);
            mStartPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
            mMode = ImageTouchMode.DRAG;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            mOldDist = spacing(event);
            if (mOldDist > 10f) {
                mSavedMatrix.set(mMatrix);
                midPoint(mMidPoint, event);
                mMode = ImageTouchMode.ZOOM;
            }
            mLastTouchEvent = new float[4];
            mLastTouchEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
            mLastTouchEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
            mLastTouchEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
            mLastTouchEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
            mRotationDegrees = rotation(event);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: //first finger lifted
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: //second finger lifted
            mMode = ImageTouchMode.NONE;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
            break;


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mMode == ImageTouchMode.DRAG) {
                float xDelta = event.getX() - mStartPoint.x;
                float yDelta = event.getY() - mStartPoint.y;
                mMatrix.set(mSavedMatrix);
                mMatrix.postTranslate(xDelta, yDelta);
            } else if (mMode == ImageTouchMode.ZOOM && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                float newDist = spacing(event);
                mMatrix.set(mSavedMatrix);
                if (newDist > 10f) {
                    float scale = newDist / mOldDist;
                    Log.d(TAG, "Scale to " + scale);
                    mMatrix.postScale(scale, scale, mMidPoint.x, mMidPoint.y);

                }
                if (mLastTouchEvent != null) {
                    float newRot = rotation(event);
                    float r = newRot - mRotationDegrees;
                    mMatrix.postRotate(r, getMeasuredWidth() / 2,
                            getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
                }
            }

            break;
    }
    // Perform the transformation
    setImageMatrix(mMatrix);

    return true; // indicate event was handled
}

 private boolean hitTestInImageMatrix(MotionEvent event) {

    float[] values = new float[9];
    mMatrix.getValues(values);
    float globalX = values[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
    float globalY = values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
    float width = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X] * getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    float height = values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y] * getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    if (x > globalX && x < (globalX + width) && y > globalY && y <
            (globalY + height)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Hit test inside!");
        return true;
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Hit test outside");
        return false;
    }
}
```

This works pretty good initially, but as soon as the image is rotated to some degree the hit test no longer works correctly.

How could I correctly detect that the touch event happens inside the transformed matrix after rotation?